# How to find find max value in a sequenced of objects?

Tags: scala

I would like to find an object with has a max int value from a sequence using Scala methods zip and max. For example I have a complex object with nested object.

```
case class A(prop1: String, b: B, prop2:String)
case class B(val:Int, prop1: String)

Seq[A]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `maxBy` on the sequence. For example (edited lightly so that it'll compile):

```
case class B(value: Int, prop1: String)
case class A(prop1: String, b: B, prop2: String)

val as = Seq(
  A("", B(10, ""), ""),
  A("foo", B(1, "bar"), "qux"),
  A("John", B(3, "Mary"), "Bob")
)
```

And then:

```
scala> as.maxBy(_.b.value)
res0: A = A(,B(10,),)
```

The argument to `maxBy` is just a function from `A` to something that the compiler can tell how to order (more specifically anything with an `Ordering` instance). The compiler knows how to compare integers, so we can just use `_.b.value`, which is sugar for something like `(a: A) => a.b.value`.

You could also provide an `Ordering` instance for `A` and just use `max`:

```
scala> implicit val orderingA: Ordering[A] = Ordering.by(_.b.value)
orderingA: Ordering[A] = scala.math.Ordering$$anon$9@3341afc6

scala> as.max
res1: A = A(,B(10,),)
```

But `maxBy` is probably more appropriate for a one-off operation.